# how to create a count of true returns in c#

Tags: c#, methods

I have made a program that reads an input of a bunch of random numbers and tests them to see if they meet certain criteria. If they meet the criteria then the method returns true.

What i'm wondering is whether or not there is a way I can keep a total of how many values return true.

To save space ill just post the input method and the count method I have started to use!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is where I am at so far...

```
public bool Requirement(int input, int countOfTrue)
    {
        if (input % 8 == 0 && input % 11 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("True");
            countOfTrue = countOfTrue + 1;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

public int TotalTrue(int countOfTrue)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Number of True: ");
        return countOfTrue;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change it to:

```
public bool Requirement(int input, ref int countOfTrue)
{
    if (input % 8 == 0 && input % 11 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("True");
        countOfTrue = countOfTrue + 1;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Adding `ref` will modify the original variable, not just the stack-local one.

As Kevin pointed out, you actually can't use `out` since the variable won't get assigned if the `if` condition is false.

Comment: You cannot use out in this case. You must use the ref keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a `property` for `true` count instead of making method. The would save the method call and also space for code. Saving space with wrong design is not a good practice. You can use the `ref` to send the initial value that could be incremented but you would need to save the returned `value` to be used for next call.

```
public TotalTrueCount {get; set;}

public bool Requirement(int input)
{
    if (input % 8 == 0 && input % 11 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("True");
        TotalTrueCount++;

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best and most consice way is to use the `FindAll` method, which is designed specifically for this.

```
var numbers = new List<int>();

// read the numbers into the list (e.g. from file)

var results = numbers.FindAll(num => num % 8 == 0 && num % 11 == 0); // returns a new list with all the numbers matching your predicate
var resultsCount = results.Count; // number of resulting numbers
```